# preg_replace inside preg_replace_callback not working

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to edit a string that consists of a phone numbers. But preg_replace that should remove all symbols but numbers - is not working.

```
$phones = preg_replace_callback(
'/((\(\+\d{5}\)|\+?\d{5})-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\+?\d{12})/',
function ($matches) {
    echo "<br />".$matches[0];
    preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$matches[0]);
    echo "<br />".$matches[0];
    echo "<br />+".substr($matches['0'], 0, 5)."-".substr($matches['0'], 5, 7);
},
$stringWithPhoneNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either save your result in a variable

```
preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$matches[0], $matches2);
#                                          ^^^
```

or return it. Otherwise, you are operating on the initial `$matches` array which does not get changed. Additionally, `[^0-9]+` can be shortened to `\D+`.